# Get width of CardView in Adapter.onBindViewHolder

Tags: android, android-layout, android-recyclerview, android-cardview

I have a list of posts and most of them are pictures (simply put it is posts just like G+ or FB apps). Each post entry has an image aspect ratio, so I can set image height based on it's width even before image was loaded from server, so card layout wouldn't change on load.

The problem is `layout_width="match_parent"` set for both card and post image. When I get width of cardview it is zero. So i can't calculate height.

For now the only solution I see is to take width of parent container (RecyclerView) and deduct all paddings, but it doesn't look like a good solution.

Is there any other way to do it?

Here is an example of adapter code

```
@Override
public void onBindViewHolder(ViewHolder holder, int position) {
    ....
    int width = holder.itemView.getWidth();
    ....
    //do some calculations
}
```

Layouts (without irrelevant parts)

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<android.support.v7.widget.CardView xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:card_view="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    android:id="@+id/card"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:descendantFocusability="blocksDescendants"
    android:foreground="?android:attr/selectableItemBackground"
    card_view:cardBackgroundColor="#ffffff"
    card_view:cardCornerRadius="3dp">

    <RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content">

        <include
            android:id="@+id/includedPost"
            layout="@layout/post_details" />    
    </RelativeLayout>
</android.support.v7.widget.CardView>
```

includedPost:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content">
    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/postImage"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_below="@+id/commenterImage"
        android:minHeight="120dp"
        android:scaleType="centerCrop" />

</RelativeLayout>
```

Comment: Can you put part of code where you call getWidth method (with a 0 result) ?

Comment: Updated my question with sample code

Comment: Maybe you could try to call getWidth() method in [onViewAttachedToWindow](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/support/v7/widget/RecyclerView.Adapter.html#onViewAttachedToWindow(VH)) according to the doc : "This can be used as a reasonable signal that the view is about to be seen by the user"

Comment: Just tried it. It works for views that are recycled but newly created are still has width equal to 0.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

when `onBind` or `onViewAttachedToWindow` is called, the child is **not** measured yet so you cannot get the width. Even if these calls were made after child is measured, what you are trying to do would not be a good practice because changing height will require a new measurement.

If you are using LinearLayoutManager, it will give the full width to the child (expect RecyclerView padding and child's margins). It is not great but OK to derive your height from there.

Another (more flexible) approach here is to create a custom ImageView that keeps your aspect ratio. When onBind is called, you'll set the desired aspect ratio of your custom ImageView.
When on measure is called, it will measure depending on your aspect ratio.

```
class MyImageView extends ImageVIew {
      ....
      private float mScale = 1f;

      public void setScale(int scale) {
          mScale = scale;
      }

      @Override
      protected void onMeasure(int widthMeasureSpec, int heightMeasureSpec) {

          super.onMeasure(widthMeasureSpec, heightMeasureSpec);

          int width = getMeasuredWidth();
          setMeasuredDimension(width, width * mScale);
      }
}
```

So in your onBind method, you call setScale on the ImageView depending on your w/h ratio.

I have not tested but this approach should work as desired.

Comment: really brilliant but setMeasuredDimension is a little bit confusing in your exampe:

int width = getMeasuredWidth();
int height = getMeasuredHeight();
setMeasuredDimension((int)(width * mScale), height);

Answer (score 0):

You can use Picasso Transformation to achieve this.

**FitToTargetViewTransformation class:**

```
import android.graphics.Bitmap;
import android.view.View;

import com.squareup.picasso.Transformation;

/**
 * Picasso Transformation class to fit image to target View size
 */
public class FitToTargetViewTransformation implements Transformation {
  private View view;

  public FitToTargetViewTransformation(View view) {
    this.view = view;
  }

  @Override
  public Bitmap transform(Bitmap source) {
    int targetWidth = view.getWidth();

    double aspectRatio = (double) source.getHeight() / (double) source.getWidth();
    int targetHeight = (int) (targetWidth * aspectRatio);
    if (source.getHeight() >= source.getWidth()) {
      return source;
    }
    Bitmap result = Bitmap.createScaledBitmap(source, targetWidth, targetHeight, false);
    if (result != source) {
      // Same bitmap is returned if sizes are the same
      source.recycle();
    }
    return result;
  }

  @Override
  public String key() {
    return "transformation" + " desiredWidth";
  }
}
```

And somewhere in onBindViewHolder you do something like this:

```
Picasso.with(context)
    .load(AVATAR_ENDPOINT)
    .transform(new FitToTargetViewTransformation(feedViewHolder.icAvatar))
    .into(feedViewHolder.icAvatar);
```

Comment: I don't believe it solves my problem. I have no problem with scaling images. My problem is settings size of ImageView before image was loaded to prevent further resizes of cards whenever some of images was loaded